# Global asa error handling doesnt work anymore in vs2013?

Tags: c#, error-handling, web-config, visual-studio-2013, global-asax

I'm following the approach of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/620559/2274562

Until last week, everything is running fine. I was using vs2012 and the error works greats, the result was like this one result here:
http://instarating.validando.com.br/asdasd

But this week I upgraded my vs to vs2013. After a lot of headache with mvc5 upgrades, I stuck again in this one. Now, the approach to error handling, just gave me an html page, like this image.

[image]

Apparently, the web.config is ok. I dont know either how to search for this problem in google, and waste like 2hours by now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try-error, I make it to work again.

Put Response.End(); after the controler.execute.

Works like a charms